# Layering 2 Audio Files at Set Times in Node.js

Tags: node.js, audio, ffmpeg, sox

Just typed a massive question and realised I was wasting space and time, so I shortened it, will answer any questions of context if needed:

**PROBLEM**

I have a **short audio file "name.mp3"** and a **long audio file "Vocals.mp3"**, and i'm trying to make an output file where the audio from **"name.mp3" occurs multiple times** over "Vocals.mp3"**.

For the sake of this thread lets just say every 20 seconds.

**TRIED**

So far I have been using "Fluent-ffmpeg" and have just started using "Sox-audio" but I'm open to suggestions of other packages. I have been able to split "Vocals.mp3" into parts and concatenate "Name.mp3" inbetween, but this has led to timing issues.

I have also been using the Mix() method from Sox but haven't been able to find a working system of starting each "name.mp3" input at set times.

I'll continue looking for more threads about this topic and if i find an answer i'll share it here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Addition to the answer, using sox-audio I am inputting subcommands in to delay each input a certain amount before outputting, i've used both pad and delay (essentially the same thing):

```
var command = soxCommand()
    .input(nameFile + ' -p pad ' + songData.nameTimes[1] + ' 0')
    .input('| sox - -m ' + nameFile + ' -p pad ' + songData.nameTimes[0] + ' 0')
    .input('| sox - -m ' + songFull)
    .output(nameLocation);

callback(command);
```